# mysqli_connect will not pass to it functions

Tags: php, mysqli

I am conventing old mysql to mysqli and run into a problem, which is that my mysqli_connect will not work in any my functions. after looking on the internet I found that it was a scope problems so i passed the mysqli_connect variable on to the function. which did not work. here are my two error

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bear_mysqli\functions\cart.php on line 44
>
> Warning: Missing argument 1 for products(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bear_mysqli\shop.php on line 30 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bear_mysqli\functions\cart.php on line 40

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bear") or die ($connect_error);

function products($con)
{
    $get = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM items WHERE quantity > 0 ORDER BY id DESC ');
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you called `products($con)` (line 30, shop.php). The error suggests that you forgot to pass its argument.  Redefining the function to accept an argument is not sufficient.

Comment: + for *I am conventing old mysql to mysqli*.

Comment: And the other error isn't fully discernable from the posted code, but likely relates to a variable scope issue where `$con` was either not passed or not defined in the right scope to begin with.

Comment: thanks just add it to the page that call it

Answer (score -1):

```
function f1(){
  $get = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], "SELECT * FROM location");
}
```

If you write `$GLOBALS['con']` then `$con` variable is treated as global so you can use it now in any function.